# How to set a universal keyboard shortcut for a variable menu item

Tags: keyboard, mojave, shortcut

I'd like to set

> ⌥, (Option-Comma)

to Hide a window in MacOS, but unfortunately the menu says "Hide [name of program]" instead of the static "Hide" how can I make a key shortcut to this menu item (FOR ALL PROGRAMS, I don't want to do them one by one 100 times) if it's always different?

Also, I don't want to use ⌘H because that takes to long, I like minimize because it's fast, but I prefer hide.

(MacBook with Mojave)

Comment: I don't understand how Cmd-H "takes to long." What about this shortcut takes too long?

Comment: With minimize I only need to use my thumb and pointer finger really close together, and it's really fast. With hide I have to reach across the keyboard, which I wouldn't normally mind but I like to navigate macOS as fast as possible, and hide is faster than minimize. (Short Answer: Hide takes two hands)